Running an executable with `cabal` in an environment that contains the `cabal`-managed package DB
I have a program A that internally calls GHC-as-an-API to compile some other Haskell module B. B has external dependencies (incl. compile-time plugins) that are recorded in the .cabal file as dependencies for A.
If I run that program via stack run A inside my project directory, everything works out: stack seems to set up the environment correctly that by the time it gets to calling GHC functions, those functions run in a context with the dependency packages set up correctly.
If I run that program via cabal run A instead, then it doesn't work: A starts running, and as soon as it gets to calling GHC to compile B, that step fails because GHC cannot find the plugin module.
How can I use cabal to run my program A locally from my project directory in a context where the GHC package database is set up to contain all Cabal-tracked dependencies?
(If anyone is curious, in my case A is a Shakefile, B is some Clash code, and the external plugin that it fails to find GHC.TypeLits.KnownNat.Solver)

Perhaps related: I noticed that cabal exec -- ghc-pkg --list only lists the global package DB, not the local cabal-managed one, unlike stack exec -- ghc-pkg --list.

Yes, I really miss this feature. cabal exec used to set up environment variables right, and it doesn't any more.

I think the most correct (manual) way to do this is

Remove the dependencies of A that are not dependencies of B.
Write (or have A write) a mock cabal file for B with all its dependencies (in a separate directory).
Use cabal install B --only-dependencies --lib --package-env ./some/file to have cabal prepare B's package environment.
Have A set -package-env or GHC_ENVIRONMENT to the file you wrote out above when calling ghc to compile B.
(Try not to call cabal install twice on the same package environment file, as at least as of a few years ago it doesn't work. Simply create it anew if B's configuration changes.)

You may also consider making A the custom-setup script for B, and marking B itself as autogen-modules. This automates the above process. Note that, again, A and B will have independent dependency lists (setup-depends vs build-depends). It is the Right Thing to treat A and B as independent entities living in different compilation environments.

Isn't this all under the assumption that B is compiled by GHC proper, instead of some highly customized compiler that just happens to be implemented in terms of the GHC API? In reality, A is written in Haskell and B is written in Clash, so A uses Clash, which in turn uses GHC.

A GHC compilation started through the GHC API can still have it's packageEnv set, and even if you leave that unset I'd be surprised if GHC didn't still use the GHC_ENVIRONMENT variable.
